# @google-cloud/functions-emulator is installed, but "-bash: functions: command not found"

Tags: google-cloud-functions, emulation

I'm following the @google-cloud/functions-emulator [installation steps](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/emulator) and observing the following:

[image]

all other commands are working, so I'm lead to believe this is a problem with this package, but perhaps I have missed something? **Anyone have any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this?**

Answer (score 0):

find "functions" and add to $PATH variable

```
cd ~
find . -name "functions"
```

> ./.nvm/versions/node/v11.9.0/lib/node_modules/node/bin/functions
>   ./.nvm/versions/node/v11.9.0/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-emulator/bin/functions
>   ...

```
nano ~/.bash_profile #append next line
```

> export
>   PATH=$PATH:~/.nvm/versions/node/v11.9.0/lib/node_modules/node/bin

Answer (score 0):

most likely, it wasn't installed globally:

```
sudo npm install -g @google-cloud/functions-emulator
```

because directory `/usr/bin` is by default on `$PATH`:

```
$ which functions
/usr/bin/functions
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Mac, try this

```
alias functions="`npm config get prefix`/bin/functions-emulator"
```

Good luck